# portlet-mvc 3.0 + maven for websphere portlet: examples?

Tags: maven-2, spring-mvc, portlet, websphere-portal

I'm trying to develop a websphere portal portlet using java, maven and spring-portlet-mvc 3.0.2.RELEASE but so far I'm not having a lot of luck.
The problem that I'm having is that a lot of the tutorials are either outdated, incorrect, contradict eachother or a combination of all the above.
Also I have to use RAD but the tutorials also contradict eachother, logically I'd think you'd choose new portlet project, but http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0802_patil-pt1/0802_patil-pt1.html says to use a dynamic webproject.

So I was wondering if anyone had a nice example/good tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The [Portlets in Action](http://www.manning.com/sarin/) book is a very good introduction to portlets. There are a couple of chapters devoted to Spring3 portlets.

Also, for WebSphere Portal portlets it might be worth taking a look at the [WebSphere Portlet Factory plugin](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/genservers/portletfactory/) for eclipse. It doesn't use Spring or Maven, but it makes it very easy to whip together WebSphere portlets very quickly, if you're not too concerned about how it does it.